# String cannot start with Å, Ä, Ö

Tags: php

Why is it, when i shorten a string. Letter "å, ä, ö" becomes "?"?
If i use the Name "Örjan" it becomes "Orjan".
But when i use "Björn", it works all fine?

**PHP**

```
//Create initials
$usr_fname_f_letter = $_POST['usr_fname'];
$usr_fname_f_letter = $usr_fname_f_letter[0];
$usr_lname_f_letter = $_POST['usr_lname'];
$usr_lname_f_letter = $usr_lname_f_letter[0];
$usr_inits = $usr_fname_f_letter .= $usr_lname_f_letter;

echo $_POST['usr_fname'];
echo '<br>';
echo $_POST['usr_lname'];
echo '<br>';
echo $usr_fname_f_letter;
echo '<br>';
echo $usr_lname_f_letter;
echo '<br>';
echo $usr_inits;
echo '<br>';
```

**RESULT**

Örjan
Björnsson
�B
B
�B

Comment: I do know that the � symbol most of the times means there's something with UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$usr_fname_f_letter = $usr_fname_f_letter[0];
```

simply takes the first (zero offset) **byte** from `$usr_fname_f_letter`; but you're using a **multibyte** character set and that's like chopping part of a character in half.

Use

```
mb_substr($usr_fname_f_letter, 0, 1, 'UTF-8')
```

because the mb_* functions are multi-byte character set aware; and work in characters, not in bytes

Answer (score 0):

I assume your encoding is utf-8 and you are probably printing only part of a multibyte character.
Try to use multibyte safe function, like [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php):

```
mb_substr($str, 0, 1, "UTF-8");
```